# Proper handling of errors stored in a class in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, design-patterns, error-handling, exception

I am doing a project using code igniter and I have to pass all error messages to ajax. So I'm thinking of putting them in an array. How can I go about this?

The first approach I've thought is to create a class that store all error messages and displays them, like this.

```
class errors {
    public $errorList = array();
    public function set_error($key, $message)
        $errorList[$key] = $message;
    }

    public function display_errors()
    {
        return $errorLis;
    }
}
```

I would use it like this:

```
public function upload_file()
{
    // if file not uploaded,
    set_error("file upload", $this->upload->display_errors());
}
```

Is this approach fine? What is wrong with it? What's a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flashdata](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata)
controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

 public function add_user() {  

     //insert or update code
     $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Successfully Added.');
     $this->load->view('index'); 
     }   
 }
```

view:

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('message')){?> 
    <div class="alert alert-success">  
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message')?> 
    </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: can you explain further? How is it better than my approach? How can I store them to an array using flash data? I understand it would be destroyed after the request?

Comment: But what happens if I have multiple error messages I have to send through ajax?

Comment: you can use this;

$myArr = array('value 1', 'value 1');
 
$this->session->set_flashdata('myArray', $myArr);